# Non-commuting coprime elements in finite non-abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a finite non-abelian group having two distinct primes dividing its order.
Is it always true that G has two non-commuting Sylow subgroups?

$\hskip300pt$ Thank you.

EDIT: I asked in a comment if the answer is also no if G is non-nilpotent. The answer turns out now to be affirmative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to the question as it stands, is no. A non-Abelian nilpotent group $G$ of order $p^{a}q^{b}$ where $p,q$ are distinct primes and $a,b$ are positive integers has
only two Sylow subgroups (one for $p$ and one for $q$) say $P$ and $Q$ respectively.
These commute with each other in the strongest sense that every element of $P$ commutes with every element of $Q$.

Perhaps a more natural condition for subgroups is whether they are permutable.
Two subgroups $A$ and $B$ are said to be permutable if $AB = BA$. This does not necessarily mean that all elements of $A$ commute with all elements of $B$.
In a finite nilpotent group, any two Sylow subgroups are permutable, and this condition 
characterizes nilpotent groups (I do not know who was the first to observe this). If $G$ is a finite group which is not nilpotent, $G$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup $A$ which is not normal for some prime $p.$ Then $G$ must have another Sylow $p$-subgroup $B.$ The set $AB$ has cardinality a power of $p$ greater than $|A|$, so $AB$ is not a a subgroup of $G$ by Lagrange's theorem, so it is not the case that $AB = BA$, and $A$ and $B$ are not permutable.

Later edit: In response to an expansion of the original question, it is possible to go further. If $G$ is a finite group which is not nilpotent, then there are two primes $p$ and $q$ and an element $x \in G$ of order a power of $p$ and an element $y \in G$ of order a power of $q$ such that $x$ and $y$ do not commute. There may be a simpler way to see this, but one way to do it is to use Frobenius's normal $p$-complement theorem.
Since $G$ is not nilpotent, there is a prime $p$ such that $G$ has no normal $p$-complement. By the mentioned theorem of Frobenius, there is a $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ (which need not be Sylow) such that $N_{G}(P)/C_{G}(P)$ is not a $p$-group. For some prime $q \neq p,$ there is then an element $y$ of $q$-power order in $N_{G}(P) \backslash C_{G}(P)$. There must be an element $x \in P$ such that $xy \neq yx,$ and we have the desired two elements.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think the answer is still no if G is non-nilpotent? Now I see that I was actually looking at non-nilpotent groups when I came up with this question.

Comment: @Fred: aswered in edit of original answer

Comment: Nice!$\;\;\;\;$

Comment: For the update: if $G$ is a finite group that is not nilpotent, let $P$ be a non-normal Sylow p-subgroup.  Then there is some $x$ in $G$ such that $P^x\neq P$; we can even choose $x$ to lie in a Sylow q-subgroup (consider the prime factorization of $|N_G(P)|$). Thus there is some $y\in P$ that is not fixed by $x$; that is, $y^x\neq y$.

Comment: @Steve: yes, that's much more direct.

Comment: @Steve: Could you please detail a bit more on how $x$ can be chosen in a Sylow $q$-subgroup? It is obvious though that $p$ doesn't appear in the order of $x$.

Comment: @Fred: I can't speak for Steve, but the way I see it is that there is a prime $q$ such that $N_G(P)$ does not contain a Sylow $q$-subgroup (since $P$ is not normal). Let $Q$ be a Sylow $q$-subgroup, and choose $x \in Q \backslash N_G(P).$

Answer (score 4):

I don't know that you mean by "non-commuting Sylow subgroups", but whatever you mean, the answer is no. If you mean subgroups $\text{Syl}_p$ and $\text{Syl}_q$ such that there exist $g\in\text{Syl}_p$ and $h\in\text{Syl}_q$ that don't commute, then any direct product $\text{Syl}_p\times \text{Syl}_q$ of a non-commutative $p$-group by any $q$-group is a counterexample. If you mean subgroups as above such that $\text{Syl}_p\text{Syl}_q\neq \text{Syl}_q\text{Syl}_p$, then the same counterexample works. Finally, if instead of "non-commuting" you meant non-commutative, then any non-abelian semidirect product $C_p\rtimes C_q$ is a counterexample.

Comment: I was playing with very small groups and thought the question could be true. Thanks for answering it.

Comment: @Fred You didn't get as far as $D_8\times C_3$ then? :-) That's the smallest counterexample.

Comment: No. :-( But thanks for letting me know what is the smallest example. I'll work it out. :-)

Comment: I really wanted to accept both answers, but Geoff gave us a very nice and complete answer. Sorry.

Comment: @Fred no need to be sorry. But next time, if you want to avoid this situation, ask a separate question as a separate question, not as a comment. Otherwise you can end up with five different answers to five different questions in the same thread, and then you would be in real trouble as to what to accept.